# How to get decimal results

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am expecting to get as decimal point like 30.769 but i am only getting 30 in this case. I have tried to change my int myVar to double myVar but got an error.  I have done some research but could not get it right so far. I know i have make changes in here:

```
int myVar= (int)ttl_Res.ExecuteScalar();
```

and also here:

```
COUNT(DDL_ANS)*100/@myVar
```

But here is my current code:

```
   if (TYPE.SelectedValue == "sometype")
            {
                con.Open();
                int myVar= (int)ttl_Res.ExecuteScalar();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "Update SETS  set SCORE = x.Result from (select ID, Type, COUNT(DDL_ANS)*100/@myVar AS Result from JATG) as x where ID = 1211";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@myVar", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = myVar;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                //con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Cast it to a floating point data type first.

Comment: like this: float myVar= (float)ttl_Res.ExecuteScalar(); ?  just want to make sure where i need to make the changes. thanks

Comment: What was the error when "tried to change my `int myVar` to `double myVar`"?

Comment: i am getting this error: Specified cast is not valid.  this time i tried to use float and also tried to as double and here where i am making the changes: float myVar = (float)ttl_Res.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: How query/stored proc for `ttl_Res.ExecuteScalar` looks like? It looks like it indeed returns `int` (even if you expect `float`). Try to save result into `object myVar = ttl_Res.ExecuteScalar()` and check its type (`myVar.GetType()`)

Comment: thanks Alexei, that is right ttl_Res.ExecuteScalar() is returning an int like 26 but my COUNT(DDL_ANS) is 8 so 8*100/26 = 30.769.  so this is what i am trying to get as my final answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `COUNT(DDL_ANS)*100/@myVar` returns an `int` is because all three operands (`COUNT(DDL_ANS)`, `100` and `@myVar`) are `int`. To get a `decimal` result it should be sufficient to cast one operand to `decimal`, for example `COUNT(DDL_ANS)*CONVERT(DECIMAL,100)/@myVar`.

Comment: thanks Tom, your answer had solved my problem.  Is there a way i can only show 2 decimal? or round to 2 decimals?  many thanks

Comment: @moe Check out the ROUND() function. Or maybe set the data type of the SCORE column to DECIMAL(28,2).

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly convert it to a double with [Convert.ToDouble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayes1wa5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The error could be because of an overflow but it depends what the integer is.

Comment: +0: I doubt it is the solution - likely `ExecuteScalar` returns `int` and no way to magically obtain `30.xxx` out of it.

Comment: okay, can i get my result as decimal in here: COUNT(DDL_ANS)*100/@myVar how can i make sure my result are decimal?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `Decimal` instead.

```
var myVar= (Decimal) ttl_Res.ExecuteScalar(); // Assuming your first column in the first row your query contains a value with decimal points
```